# Delete unnecessary fields from acts_as_votable gem migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

Rails `acts_as_votable` gem generates current set of fields:

```
:cached_votes_score
:cached_votes_total
:cached_weighted_total
:cached_weighted_average
:cached_votes_up     
:cached_votes_down   
:cached_weighted_score
```

Which fields can be deleted so that only the average result of voting can be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable#caching), caching is optional, used to improve performance. If they have no need to you, you can simply erase the columns.

> To speed up perform you can add cache columns to your votable model's table. These columns will automatically be updated after each vote.